# pyMongo set value as array

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'd like to perform this action, but all it sets is empty array. How should I do this ? :

```py
databaseHier = ["data!",
    "vdsv",
    "bdfs",
    "23ty6gdsfbasd",
]
dbCol.update_one({"cfg": "configurationDetails"}, {"$set": {"content": databaseHier}})
```

My document before:

```
{
    _id:5ec27d64984c2c5e41380939
    name:"project2"
    myId:"66ca2ab3-c67c-4339-9ed9-508256cd2651"
    cfg:"configurationDetails"
}
```

Document after:

```
{
    _id:5ec27d64984c2c5e41380939
    name:"project2"
    myId:"66ca2ab3-c67c-4339-9ed9-508256cd2651"
    cfg:"configurationDetails"
    content : Array [0:""]
}
```

Comment: What does your document look like before and after attempted update? Your code works fine for me on a test document without any filter.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere I've updated main question above. Thanks!

Comment: @Dariusz : not sure why, did you check if it's an array prior to query.. `dbCol` is it just db.collection('collectionName') ? Or some schema kind of thing ?

Comment: @Dariusz The update statement looks alright to me. It does set the array _with its elements_  to the `content` field. Your update's query filter is `"cfg": "configurationDetails"` - which means that the statement is updating the first matching document - not necessarily that particular document you have posted. So, just check if there are multiple documents in your collection with the same value for `cfg`.

Comment: Hey @prasad_ thanks for helping! 
Nope its 1 document in database and it does add the Array to it. But array is just 0:""

Comment: @Dariusz, it works perfectly fine for me. Just check once, whether `dbCol` is mapped to correct collection/database or not?

Comment: Hmmm I don't get it. Yes its mapped to collect collective/database since its adding content key and Array as value. But the value is incorrect :/ Sigh. Maybe I have never version than you and theres a bug?

Comment: Could you mention the version of MongoDB and PyMongo?